# Calculate Expected value using conditioning

Tags: expected-value

How to calculate E[X] using conditioning. Let a random variable Y = X^2, While X is a random variable that can take the following values {-2,-1,0,1,2}. Each value can occur with equal probability i.e., 1/5.

Comment: What's the question?  If the goal is to compute $E[X]$, where does $Y$ come in?

Comment: @lulu I think Y will be used as following formula could be used to find E[X]........"E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]"  But I'm not so much sure about that.

Comment: But $E[X]=0$, obviously.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{n=0}^2 \mathbb E[X\mid Y=n]\mathbb P(Y=n)\\
&=\mathbb E[X\mid Y=0]\cdot\frac15 + \mathbb E[X\mid Y=1]\cdot\frac25 + \mathbb E[X\mid Y=4]\cdot\frac25\\
&=0+0+0=0.
\end{align}

Comment: How could we have $Y = 2$ since $Y = X^2$?

Comment: Good point, I have changed it to $Y=4$.

Comment: @Math1000 isn't the probability for Y=4 is 2/5 ? Well the ans will still be zero but just for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

$$ E(X) = \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(-2) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(-1) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(0) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(1) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(2) $$
$$ E(X) = \frac{ -2 -1 + 1 + 2} {5} $$
$$ E(X) = 0 $$
Now for the $E(Y)$.
$$ E(Y) = \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)((-2)^2) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)((-1)^2) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(0^2) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(1^2) + \left( \frac{1}{5} \right)(2^2) $$
$$ E(Y) = \frac{ 4 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 4}{5} $$
$$ E(Y) = \frac{10}{5} = 2 $$

Comment: This is just a simple method but I'm supposed to find E[X] by conditioning method.

Comment: @Xzcess I have not heard of the conditioning method. Are you sure you have that term right?